# Pritunl server connection issues

Tags: python, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, pritunl

I created Pritunl Server successfully on my ubuntu 20.04 vps.
Then when I try to connect to it using openvpn, I get a log message everytime...

The log is:

```
Sun Nov 28 18:58:55 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sun Nov 28 18:58:55 2021 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sun Nov 28 18:58:55 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]95.216.249.231:16528
Sun Nov 28 18:58:55 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)
Sun Nov 28 18:58:55 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]95.216.249.231:16528
Sun Nov 28 18:58:59 2021 Server poll timeout, restarting
Sun Nov 28 18:58:59 2021 SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
```

But when I use a seperate proxy, It connects to vpn and works without any problems...
What is the problem?